# How to read the contents of a file using bash, then split the lines in that file, and call a java program with them as arguments?

Tags: java, bash

I have a simple calculator which makes use of RMI. The client takes 3 arguments, operand1, operand2 and operator. It can be invoked by the following:

`java SingleCalculatorClient 8 9 /`

And the output should be this:

```
ebin@tux:~/DS$ java SingleCalculatorClient 8 9 +
Expected result of 8+9(by direct operation) : 17
Popped value of 8+9from stack : 17
```

For testing multiple clients accessing the same server, I have a text file which has some lines with the format operand1, operand2 and operator. A sample file as follows:

```
5 4 +
6 7 /
8 8 -
```

I have a bash script, which reads the file, the split the lines, the call the java Client within it. Script as follows :

```
#!/bin/bash
input="test.txt"
while IFS= read -r var
do
  stringarray=( $var )
  java SingleCalculatorClient ${stringarray[0]} ${stringarray[1]} ${stringarray[2]}
done < "$input"
```

Somehow, when I run this, the java output is very weird. A sample output is this :

```
ebin@tux:~/DS$ ./script.sh 
4(by direct operation) : 0
4from stack : 0 5+
7(by direct operation) : 0
7from stack : 0 6/
8(by direct operation) : 0
8from stack : 0 8-
```

**Even if it is just one line in the file, the output is always 0**. And I do not understand why the output statements are truncated.

If I try to print the split words in bash, it turns out to be correct. If I echo it, this is the output:

```
ebin@tux:~/DS$ ./script.sh 
5 4 +
6 7 /
8 8 -
```

And instead of reading the file and split words, if I just call the java client with some arguments within the bash script, it works as well.

This is the java part which takes the arguments,and then push to a stack:

```
               int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
               int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
               String operation = args [2];
               if(operation.equals("x"))
                operation="*";

               Calculator calculator = (Calculator) Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1:1100/CalculatorOperations");
               calculator.pushValue(x);
               calculator.pushValue(y);
               calculator.pushOperator(operation);
```

On the stack,it is just popping values, and do the arithmetic using switch statements.

So I think the problem is somewhere in splitting the words, but not sure.Can anyone help me to point out where is the problem and how to solve it ?

Comment: Add your java code to your question.

Comment: Are you on Windows, and forgot to use Unix newlines? See [Before asking about problematic code](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) in the Bash tag info...

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I am on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @tuxebin: yet it seems you're having `\r` in your file `text.txt`. Check that with `cat -v` (as suggested in the link I gave).

Comment: Unrelated comment: you will have problems as soon as you start using the product operation `*`: that's because you're badly splitting the string `var`: with `stringarray=( $var )`, you're subject to pathname expansion! I have no idea where you learned that, but please never use it again (and if you saw it on this site, please downvote the answer that shows this). Also, you're not using quotes where you should: all the expansions must be quoted: `"${stringarray[0]}"`, `"${stringarray[1]}"`, etc. _with double quotes._

Comment: Add output of `cat -A test.txt` to your question.

Comment: @Inian: your answer is fine `:)`.

Comment: everyone.. thank you very much for helping me to point out the issue. The culprit was that text file. Creating a new file fixed it. Also, as you mentioned, cat -v showed that additional character.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I do not understand what do you mean in the second comment. Is it that in my current code, there will be problems when I encounter * in the text file ? If that is, my text file will not contain *, it will be replaced by x.

Comment: tuxebin: if you have a single `*` in your text file, and use your script and not Inian's script below, the `*` will be replaced by all the files in the current directory. You can try it: `var='*';  stringarray=( $var ); declare -p stringarray`. With Inian's answer, (using `read` to split the string) you won't have any problems with globbing.

Comment: got it. Thank you very much for enlightening me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *NOT* reset the input field separator `IFS=` , it needs to have its default value of `tab/space/newline` to access individual fields in a line.
Also you are missing the `-a` option, which `read` needs to read into array so you can access the individual elements. i.e.

```
input="test.txt"
while read -r -a var
do
  java SingleCalculatorClient "${var[0]}" "${var[1]}" "${var[2]}"
done < "$input"
```

Or) you don't need an array just use individual variables for `read`

```
input="test.txt"
while read -r op1 op2 op
do
  java SingleCalculatorClient "$op1" "$op2" "$op"
done < "$input"
```

---

#### Note:-

On a side note, if you are copy pasting code from Windows to the Linux machine, remove the `DOS CRLF` endings by running `dos2unix script.sh`

Comment: @tuxebin: Refer my update, remove `IFS=` and try. It should solve your problem

Comment: Its the same :(

Comment: @tuxebin: It is beyond the scope of `bash`, you need to check your `java` code.

Comment: running it manually gives correct output. Running inside a bash script, but giving the arguments explicitly also works. So could it be a java issue ?

Comment: @tuxebin : You could accept the answer if it solved your problem